# Ruby / Rails - How to aggregate a Query Results in an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a large data set that I want to clean up for the user. The data set from the DB looks something like this:

```
ID | project_id | thread_id | action_type |description
 1 | 10         | 30        |  comment    | yada yada yada yada yada
 1 | 10         | 30        |  comment    | xxx
 1 | 10         | 30        |  comment    | yada 313133
 1 | 10         | 33        |  comment    | fdsdfsdfsdfsdfs
 1 | 10         | 33        |  comment    | yada yada yada yada yada
 1 | 10         |           | attachment  | fddgaasddsadasdsadsa
 1 | 10         |           | attachment  | xcvcvxcvxcvxxcvcvxxcv
```

Right now, when I output the above in my view its in the very same order as above, problem is it is very repetitive. For example, for project_id 10 & thread_id 30 you see:

```
10 - 30 - yada yada yada yada yada
10 - 30 - xxxxx
10 - 30 - yada yada yada yada yada
```

What I would like to learn how to do in ruby, is some how create an array and aggreate descriptions under a project_id and thread_id, so instead the output is:

```
10 - 30
 - yada yada yada yada yada
 - xxxxx
 - yada yada yada yada yada
```

Any advice on where to get started? This requirement is new for me so I would appreciate your thoughts on what you're thinking the best way to solve this is.Hopefully this can be done in ruby and not sql, as the activity feed is likely going to grow in event types and complexity.

Thanks

Comment: For a SQL approach use GROUP BY. For a Ruby approach use Enumerable#group_by. Check the docs.

Comment: What form does this data take? Is it ActiveRecord objects or JSON objects or something else?

Comment: @Pan, this data is an ActiveRecord object, like @activity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `group_by` http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by in Ruby or right in SQL. In Ruby:

```
sets = DataSet.all.group_by{ |data| [data.project_id, "-", data.thread_id].join(" ") }
```

Then you'll get Hash like that:

```
{ "10 - 30" => [#DataSet1, #DataSet2 ...], "10 - 33" => [#DataSet7, #DataSet11 ...]
```

Which you can parse in view:

```
<% sets.each do |range, datas| %>
  <p><%= range %>:</p>
  <% datas.each do |data| %>
    <p><%= data.description %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPD for each_with_index**

```
<% sets.each_with_index do |datas, index| %>
  <p><%= datas[0] %>:</p>
  <% datas[1].each do |data| %>
    <p><%= data.description %></p>
    # some stuff with *last*
    <%= "This is the last one" if data == datas[1].last %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This has to be the most impressive thing I've seen rails do yet.

Comment: I ended up needing an index, so I changed it to <% sets.each_with_index....... problem is inside the loop I need to do a datas.last and that breaks when I use the each_with_index. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I follow a simple guideline for using the `group_by` method of the `Enumerator`.
 - The data-set being operated on should be small and fixed and guaranteed to remain constant with time.

Eg:

```
Fixed data-set:  Zip codes, city names     
Dynamic but small data-set: User's hobbies    
Dynamic but paginated data-set: First page of latest orders.
```

In my opinion your activity feed table can grow rapidly with time .  The `Activity.all` loads all the activities in to memory. You are incurring excessive memory and network costs by executing this call. It is never a good idea to execute the `all` call with out conditions and pagination. If you are currently paginating to result set, the current solution will not work when the result-set spans multiple pages. You have to use the `order` clause to get correct result-set.

This is what I would do:

In your controller:

```
# order by ensures that ordering happens at the DB
# pagination and conditions ensures that data set is small
activities = Activity.paginate(:order => "project_id, thread_id", :page => #pn)
@activity_groups = activities.group_by{|a| "#{a.project_id} - #{a.thread_id}"}
```

Now, you can use the `@activity_groups` in your view as suggested by `fl00r`.